# Lottery odds: Are some tickets more valuable than others?

Tags: probability

Let's say the odds of winning a scratch-off lottery game are exactly 1 in 1000, and I purchase 100 tickets at a local convenience store. The company that makes the lottery tickets always creates them in batches of one million tickets with exactly 1000 winning tickets in each batch. After scratching-off 99 losers in a row from the 100 I bought, **is there any reason to think that the 1 remaining ticket is somewhat more likely to be a winner than a new one that somebody else might purchase at the store?**
What has me perplexed is that when I purchased the 100 tickets, there would have been a finite number of tickets in circulation - by scratching off 99 losers from that finite pool it would seem that I have effectively reduced the pool size but not the expectation of their being winners within that pool. In other words, the odds of remaining tickets in that pool being winners seem to have magically  improved. Back at the convenience store (where possibly they received a new shipment of tickets) the odds would remain 1 in 1000 though, right?

Comment: Intuition pump: Suppose instead of 99 you scratch off 999000 losers in a row. Then the probability that the next ticket you scratch off is a winner is 1, assuming all the tickets you scratch are from the same batch.

Comment: As for the question of whether the hundredth ticket in your possession has the same odds or better odds than that of a newly purchased ticket, no their odds are the same.  However... armed with the knowledge that there are $99$ fewer losing tickets out there, that changes your expectation for both the hundredth ticket in your possession *and* changes the expectation for newly purchased tickets, changing them both from $1$ in $1000$ to $1000$ in $999901$

Comment: *“Lottery: A tax on people who are bad at math.”* Ambrose Bierce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is conditional expected probability. Given that you scratched a bunch of tickets, you know that the probability of the last one being a winner is increased *only because* you know that the tickets are not independently random; there is a set $1000$ out of a million winners.

However, if each ticket was independently random (i.e each ticket had a $0.1\%$ win rate) then you'd still have the same chance.

Back to your other paradox: given that you didn't win, you now know that *all* remaining tickets have an increased chance of being a winner, including those at the store. But that's only knowing that you didn't win - a random stranger couldn't use this logic without knowing that you didn't already win.

One last note, in real life this doesn't actually matter much as the number of tickets produced is so huge that even buying a thousand tickets would barely make a dent in the 'odds' of each one, and besides I'm not sure if lottery companies ensure there are at least X winners although I could be wrong.

**Edit:** answering your title question, no, the tickets are all equally valuable before you scratch yours. After you scratch yours, the ones at the store are actually slightly more likely of being winners, but there was no way to work that out without buying your tickets first.

Comment: "*there was no way to work that out without buying (and scratching) your tickets first*"

Comment: In real life, there is no way that a lottery company should be allowed to make batches of tickets with a guaranteed number of winners in each batch. Ertxiem's quote from Ambrose Bierce is exactly right.

Comment: Also the tickets in a lottery should not be independently random as that would allow selling multiple tickets with the same number.

Comment: @RobArthan "*selling multiple tickets with the same number*"  The question was referencing scratch-off style lotteries, not powerball style lotteries.  "Selling multiple tickets with the same number" is not possible or is irrelevant to scratch-off style.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same question.  The approach I have used is based on a simple premise that as the game matures the odds *do* change.  In my State, the number and level of prizes claimed is published each day.  So my goal is to calculate the odds at time t and compare them with the initial odds; then play those games where the odds have moved into my favor.
i.e. $ OV_i = TotPrizes_i/NumTix_i $ (where OV is overall odds; i is initial)

To calculate the odds at time t obvuiously use the same formula $ OV_t = TotPrizes_t/NumTix_t $

The challenge being determining the number of tickets remaining at time t.  I have seen a couple approaches (that yield the same result):

- calculating the percentage of prizes left and multiplying that by the initial number of tickets.
- multiplying the total prizes claimed by the initial odds and subtracting from the initial number of tickets

This still uses the same ratio of prizes/tickets which violates the premise that the ratio (odds) changes as the game progresses or matures.

One factor that I am trying to consider is that there are prizes won, but not claimed as of yet.  How many of us have scratched off a winner, and yet held onto it for a couple of days before claiming that prize.  This is not accounted for in the published results. How many winning tickets are held and how many losers were purchased before the winners were discovered?  This estimate, whatever it is, would then be subtracted from the initial odds.  So the equation would look something like:
$$ NumTickets_t = NumTickets_i - (PrizesClaimed_t(OV_i - x)) $$ where x is the factor of prizes not claimed.

This is my approach which I am testing.  I am not a math genius but trying to logically deduce a method to estimate the tix remaining. Or I could just be arbitrarily adjusting the odds in my favor.

In response to Rob's comment, the State does guarantee a minimum winning $ amount per pack of tix sold

-mark